# Querying large datasets in Swift - CoreData or calls directly to sqlite-database?

Tags: swift, sqlite, core-data

I'm going to populate a large database in an upcoming app. I will load data from a web-api (in gzipped format) and then extract it on the device adding it to a sqlite-database, either through CoreData or directly via sqlite-calls. This part really doesn't matter. The database will be updated quite infrequently.

However, the app needs to query this data all the time. I guess there will be somewhere around 500k rows in the database. The queries won't be very complex, but I still want to be able to query it like a database (i.e. not iterating through/sorting arrays). Those queries are read only. Is it overkill/stupid to use CoreData for this task? Will it add unnecessary overhead?

The main reason I'm even considering CoreData is because I like how neat CoreData is implemented, rather than using the old snake case C-style api-calls to a sqlite-database directly.

Comment: And there is also other options in between like GRDB and FMDB for instance

Comment: Not an overkill at all. I think you'd reimplement all the same things that CoreData already offers to you if you were to go with SQLite directly.